# bezierPath moveToPoint wrong coordinate system

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, core-animation, uibezierpath

I'm trying to animate a button along an arbitrary path. For that purpose I need to create a path which u I'm using BezierPath for.

However something weird is going on whenever I set moveToPoint to 0,0 instead of starting animation from  the top left of the screen the button appears a bit top and towards left so it is only partially visible.

What is happening here? Does moveToPoint use some other coordinate system?

The anchor point of the button is set to the standard top, left.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    bezierPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(52, 83)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(45, 59)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(65, 30)];
}

-(void)randomAnimation
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation* keyframeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    keyframeAnimation.duration = 4.0;
    keyframeAnimation.path = [bezierPath CGPath];
    [self.rndBtn.layer addAnimation:keyframeAnimation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're animating the position property of your layers, which is set to the center of the layer by default. If you set the center of your button's layer to 0,0, it will be centered at the edge of the screen, and half-off.

You need to set the starting point to width/2, height/2. Alternately you can move the anchorPoint of the layer, but that has side-effects.